# Incompatible pointer types with expressions of type NSArray

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsarray

Am getting two warnings of 'Incompatible pointer types with expressions of type NSArray' in my .m files which I have commented out.

Don't completely understand this and don't know how to fix this. Can you explain this so that I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

ItemsViewController.m

```
#import "ItemsViewController.h"
#import "BNRItemStore.h"
#import "BNRItem.h"

@implementation ItemsViewController // Incomplete implementation

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];

  NSArray *items = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore]allItems];
  BNRItem *selectedItem = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

  //Give detail view controller a pointer to the item object in a row
  [detailViewController setItem:selectedItem];

  // Push it onto the top of the navigation controller's stack
  [[self navigationController]pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}

-(id)init
{
  // Call the superclass's designated initializer
  self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
  if (self) {


  }
  return self;
}

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
  return [self init];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore]allItems]count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


  // Check for a reusable cell first, use that if it exists
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

  // If there is no reusable cell of this type, create a new one
  if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
  } 

  // Set the text on the cell with the description of the item
  // that is at the nth index of items, where n = row this cell
  // will appear in on the tableview
  BNRItem *p = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore]allItems]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

  [[cell textLabel]setText:[p description]];

  return cell;
}

-(UIView *)headerView
{
  // If we haven't loaded the headerView yet
  if (!headerView) {
    //Load HeaderView.xib
    [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
  }
  return headerView;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)sec
{
  return [self headerView];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tv heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)sec
{
  // The height of the header view should be determined from the height of the 
  // view in the XIB file
  return [[self headerView]bounds].size.height;
}

-(IBAction)toggleEditingMode:(id)sender
{
  // If we are currently in editing mode
  if ([self isEditing]) {
    // Change text of button to inform user of state
    [sender setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // Turn off editing mode
    [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
  } else {
    // Change text of button to inform user of state
    [sender setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // Enter editing mode
    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
  }
}

-(IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender
{
  // Create a new BNRItem and add it to the store
  BNRItem *newItem = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore]createItem]; //Incompatible pointer types initializing 'BNRItem *__strong' with an expression of type 'NSArray*'

  // Figure out where that item is in the array
  int lastRow = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore]allItems]indexOfObject:newItem];

  NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:0];

  // Insert this new row into the table
  [[self tableView]insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // If the table view is asking to commit a delete command...
  if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
  {
    BNRItemStore *ps = [BNRItemStore sharedStore];
    NSArray *items = [ps allItems];
    BNRItem *p = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [ps removeItem:p];

    // We also remove that row from the table view with an animation
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
  }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath 
         toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
  [[BNRItemStore sharedStore]moveItemAtIndex:[sourceIndexPath row] 
                                     toIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [[self tableView] reloadData];
}


@end
```

ItemsViewController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface ItemsViewController : UITableViewController
{
  IBOutlet UIView *headerView;
}

-(UIView *)headerView;
-(IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)toggleEditingMode:(id)sender;

@end
```

BNRItemStore.m

```
#import "BNRItemStore.h"
#import "BNRItem.h"

@implementation BNRItemStore

+(BNRItemStore *)sharedStore
{
  static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;
  if (!sharedStore) 
    sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil]init];

  return sharedStore;
}

-(id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    allItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

  }
  return self;
}

-(NSArray *)allItems
{
  return allItems;
}

-(NSArray *)createItem
{
  BNRItem *p = [BNRItem randomItem];
  [allItems addObject:p];
  return p; //Incompatible pointer types returning 'BNRItem*__strong' from a function with result type 'NSArray*'
}

-(void)removeItem:(BNRItem *)p
{
  [allItems removeObjectIdenticalTo:p];
}

-(void)moveItemAtIndex:(int)from 
               toIndex:(int)to
{
  if(from==to) {
    return;
  }
  // Get pointer to object being moved so we can re-insert it
  BNRItem *p = [allItems objectAtIndex:from];

  // Remove p from array
  [allItems removeObjectAtIndex:from];

  //Insert p in array at new location
  [allItems insertObject:p atIndex:to];
}

@end
```

BNRItemStore.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class BNRItem;

@interface BNRItemStore : NSObject
{
  NSMutableArray *allItems;
}

// Notice that this is a class method and prefixed with a + instead of a -
+(BNRItemStore *)sharedStore;

-(void)removeItem:(BNRItem *)p;
-(void)moveItemAtIndex:(int)from 
               toIndex:(int)to;

-(NSArray *)allItems;
-(NSArray *)createItem;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the return type of the method definition, and then look at the type of the var you are returning.

```
-(NSArray *)createItem
{
  BNRItem *p = [BNRItem randomItem];
  [allItems addObject:p];
  return p; //Incompatible pointer types returning 'BNRItem*__strong' from a function with result type 'NSArray*'
}
```

Seems like you should be returning `allItems` instead of `p`.

Or change the return type to `BNRItem *`.

Answer (score 2):

In here:

```
-(NSArray *)createItem
{
  BNRItem *p = [BNRItem randomItem];
  [allItems addObject:p];
  return p; //Incompatible pointer types returning 'BNRItem*__strong' from a function with result type 'NSArray*'
}
```

`p` is a variable of type `BNRItem*`. Your method claims that its return value is an `NSArray*` The warning is because these are different.

If you want to return the whole array, return `allItems`.

If you want to return the new item, change the return type.

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you. But I am still confused with the other method because I want to add a new item to the store, which is a singleton array and a container. Do I need to give it a weak relationship to BNRItemStore while BNRItemStore has a strong relationship with BNRItem? If so, how do I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)moveItemAtIndex:(int)from 
               toIndex:(int)to
```

That method is going to work as written;   if `to` is after `from`, you'll be moving the object to the wrong index and, possibly, causing an out-of-range exception in the process.

---

As others have said, your `createItem` method is declared as returning an `NSArray*` but you are returning a `BNRItem*`.

Fixing the return type will also fix the other warning.

---

In your comment to "quixoto" you are asking some modeling questions.  Sounds like you should really be using CoreData, which is designed explicitly to allow for exactly such kinds of modeling tasks.

Comment: OP is working through a tutorial book and hasn't gotten to the CoreData chapter yet.